# Git stash - Cannot apply stash back to my branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I had a few changed files, some new additions.

I run `git stash` and the changed files vanished from my changes (in Visual Studio 2013 Changes window) and the added files remain and one changed file remained.

When I tried to reapply the stash it failed:

> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

I'd expect to be able to stash, do nothing, apply back again without error.

(QA, I found the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio was altering a `csproj` file automatically, setting restore packages, so it was dirtying a file.

I could not undo the changes because VS wrote them right back immediately.

I closed VS and discarded the change from Sourcetree and then, even though my added files remained, I could apply the stash.

What is interesting is why added files aren't stashed.

Comment: "What is interesting is why added files aren't stashed." : It's the way git stash works, but you can stash everything by using `git stash --include-untracked` or `git stash -u`

Comment: Super, I'll be using that more.